# Docker build no longer working; faults at loading metadata

Tags: docker

I have a container for docker that I have built numerous times. I was playing with it this morning when it suddenly stopped working. I get the following error:

```
 => ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:14.4.0-alpine                                                                                                                            0.7s
------
 > [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:14.4.0-alpine:
 ------
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to parse /Users/myname/.docker/.token_seed: unexpected end of JSON input
```

I have tried the no-cache and pull flags. The docker file itself is very simple.

```
ARG NODE_VERSION=14.4.0-alpine

###
# STAGE 1: Base
###
FROM node:$NODE_VERSION as base

ENV NODE_PATH=/src
WORKDIR $NODE_PATH

###
# STAGE 2: Build
###
FROM base as build

COPY package.json package-lock.json .npmrc ./
RUN npm i

COPY . ./

RUN npm run build

###
# STAGE 3: Production
###
FROM node:$NODE_VERSION

ENV NODE_PATH=/src
ENV APP_PORT=3000

WORKDIR $NODE_PATH

COPY --from=build $NODE_PATH/.next ./.next
COPY --from=build $NODE_PATH/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=build $NODE_PATH/src ./src
COPY --from=build $NODE_PATH/package.json ./
COPY --from=build $NODE_PATH/.babelrc ./
COPY --from=build $NODE_PATH/LICENSE ./

EXPOSE $APP_PORT

CMD npm start
```

Comment: Take a look at the /Users/myname/.docker/.token_seed file. Is it empty or incomplete?
Maybe just deleting it ( and .token_seed.lock) will fix it.

Comment: And now it's doing the same thing again, but this time that didn't solve my problem and docker won't open

Comment: Maybe you can provide more information about the system configuration, docker version, os, build command...
According to [this issue](https://github.com/docker/buildx/issues/547) its maybe related to a shortage on disc space.

Answer (score 0):

If your disk is full, docker will be unable to write the file, `~/.docker/.token_seed`.

1. `df -h;` to verify that you are low on disk space
2. `docker system prune;` or whatever you need to do to reclaim some disk space
3. `rm ~/.docker/.token_seed*;`

Now you can do your docker deeds with a freshly capable system.